# How to properly create a tar archive to import with docker

Tags: docker, tar

I need to extract the filesystem of a debian image onto the host, modify it, then repackage it back into a docker image. I'm using the following commands:

```
docker export container_name > archive.tar
tar -xf archive.tar -C debian/
```

modifying the file system here

```
tar -cpjf archive-modified.tar debian/
docker import archive-modified.tar debian-modified
docker run -it debian-modified /bin/bash
```

After I try to run the new docker image I get the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

I've tried the above steps without modifying the file system at all and I get the same behavior. I've also tried importing the output of `docker export` directly, and this works fine. This probably means I'm creating the new tar archive incorrectly. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Export and import are the wrong commands if you want to work with an image vs a container. You flatten the layers, and lose the image metadata like the entrypoint, path, and configuration settings. There's `save` and `load` for images, but if you use that, you'll need to learn how to set the digest in the various locations it's used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the archive generated by `docker export`:

```
# tar tf archive.tar | sort | head
bin/
bin/bash
bin/cat
bin/chgrp
bin/chmod
bin/chown
bin/cp
bin/dash
bin/date
bin/dd
```

And then at the archive you generate with your `tar -cpjf ...` command:

```
# tar tf archive-modified.tar | sort | head
debian/
debian/bin/
debian/bin/bash
debian/bin/cat
debian/bin/chgrp
debian/bin/chmod
debian/bin/chown
debian/bin/cp
debian/bin/dash
debian/bin/date
```

You've moved everything into a `debian/` top-level directory, so there is no `/bin/bash` in the image (it would be `/debian/bin/bash`, and probably wouldn't work anyway because your shared libraries aren't in the expected location, either.

You probably want to create the updated archive like this:

```
# tar -cpjf archive-modified.tar -C debian/ .
```